# Deserializing JSON to a blessed object

Tags: json, perl, serialization

The accepted answer to ["How to convert Perl objects into JSON and vice versa"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185482/how-to-convert-perl-objects-into-json-and-vice-versa) says that the conversion is hairy.

Does anyone actually use JSON for deserialization of nested blessed objects? How?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example ? What is your definition of "Blessing" in the `R` context.

Comment: @dickoa: not `R`! `Perl`!

Comment: When I commented this question the `r` tag was in this question and no `perl` tag. I was confused but now everything make sense (you corrected it).

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSYNC](http://p3rl.org/JSYNC).

```
perl -Moose=Foo -MJSYNC -e'
    has "attr", is => "rw", isa => "HashRef[HashRef]", default => sub { { 0 => { 1 => { 3 => 4} } } };
    print JSYNC::dump(Foo->new)
'
{"!":"!perl/hash:Foo","attr":{"0":{"1":{"3":"4"}}}}
```

Comment: JSYNC does not appear to be stable enough (not even in ubuntu!)

Comment: You have a strange definition of stable.

Comment: Strange or not - I have given up on cpan and I need my code to work on Ubuntu and CentOS, so things which cannot be installed with aptitude and yum are beyond my reach.

Comment: That's something different now. You should learn how to make your own package, it appears you haven't done so yet. Running `dh-make-perl` or `cpanspec` isn't rocket surgery.