# function to print document in json format (mongodb)

Tags: json, perl, mongodb

Hi I'm using perl to query mongodb, when I get back a cursor how can I print the documents in json format

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51fdbfefb12a69cd35000502"), "biography" : "Colombian pop singer, born on February 2, 1977 to a Colombian mother of Spanish-Italian descent and an American father of Lebanese-Italian descent. Shakira is known for a high IQ and is fluent in Spanish, English, Italian and Portuguese.\r\rWriting songs and belly-dancing since childhood, her first album was released when she was a mere 14 years old. Other Spanish-language albums followed, each faring better than its predecessor, but it was not until 2001 that she achieved a world-wide breakthrough with the English-language \"Laundry Service\" album.\r", "imguri" : "http://api.discogs.com/image/A-5530-1218936486.jpeg", "index" : "shakira", "name" : "Shakira", "ready" : "yes", "requests" : "0"}
```

I dont see any function in the mongoDB module so I migh try something like this

```
run_command({printjson => $foo});
```

but It says printjson is not a function

what can I do

Thanks

Comment: where do you want to print? console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perl driver will return a cursor when you do find:

```
my $cursor = $collection->find({ i => { '$gt' => 42 } });
```

You can iterator over this `$cursor` to obtain the documents, by doing this:

```
while (my $object = $cursor->next) {
    ...
}
```

In the while loop, you can then access each field of each `$object`:

```
print $object->{i};
```

If you want, you can also convert them to JSON, but for that you need to have the [JSON CPAN module](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) installed. On Debian/Ubuntu, you can use `apt-get install libperl-json` for that, but add `use JSON;` to the start of your script. With this installed, you can put in your `while` clause:

```
while (my $object = $cursor->next) {
    my $json = encode_json $object;
    print "$json\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error but I get this error: neither allow_blessed nor convert_blessed settings are enabled

Comment: nvm found the solution to my second problem thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185482/how-to-convert-perl-objects-into-json-and-vice-versa