# Unblessing Perl objects and constructing the TO_JSON method for convert_blessed

Tags: perl, moose, moo

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185679/632407) I found a recommendation for a simple `TO_JSON` method, which is needed for serializing blessed objects to JSON.

```
sub TO_JSON { return { %{ shift() } }; }
```

Could anybody please explain in detail how it works?

I changed it to:

```
sub TO_JSON {
        my $self = shift;         # the object itself – blessed ref
        print STDERR Dumper $self;

        my %h = %{ $self };       # Somehow unblesses $self. WHY???
        print STDERR Dumper \%h;  # same as $self, only unblessed

        return { %h };    # Returns a hashref that contains a hash.
        #return \%h;      # Why not this? Works too…
}
```

Many questions… :( Simply, I’m unable to understand 3-liner Perl code. ;(

I need the `TO_JSON` but it will filter out:

- unwanted attributes and
- unset attributes too (e.g. for those the `has_${attr}` predicate returns false)

This is my code – it works but I really don't understand why the unblessing works…

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

package Some;
use Moo;

has $_ => ( is => 'rw', predicate => 1,) for (qw(a1 a2 nn xx));

sub TO_JSON {
    my $self = shift;
    my $href;
    $href->{$_} = $self->$_ for( grep {!/xx/} keys %$self );
    # Same mysterious unblessing. The `keys` automagically filters out
    # “unset” attributes without the need of call of the has_${attr}
    # predicate… WHY?
    return $href;
}

package main;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my @objs = map { Some->new(a1 => "a1-$_", a2 => "a2-$_", xx=>"xx-$_") } (1..2);
my $data = {arr => \@objs};
#say Dumper $data;
say JSON->new->allow_blessed->convert_blessed->utf8->pretty->encode($data);
```

**EDIT**: To clarify the questions:

- The `%{ $hRef }` derefences the `$hRef` (getting the hash pointed to by the reference), but why get a plain hash from a *blessed object reference* `$self`?
- In other words, why the `$self` is a hashref?
- <strike>I tried to make a hash slice like `@{$self}{ grep {!/xx/} keys %$self}` but it didn't work. Therefore I created that horrible `TO_JSON`.</strike>
- If the `$self` is a hashref, why the `keys %$self` returns only attributes having a value, and not all declared attributes (e.g. the `nn` too – see the `has`)?

Comment: Second and fourth are moose related(perl OO mostly uses hashref for object storage). Hash slice returns only values and you want key/value pairs if I'm correct.

Comment: `my %h = map { $_ => $self->{$_} } grep { !/xx/ } keys %$self` or `my %h = %$self; delete @h{ grep /xx/, keys %$self }`

Comment: @mpapec - THANX, you comment helped me find a bug. I have perl 5.20, so can use the `return { %{$self}{ grep { !/xx/ } keys %$self } };` - and it finally works :) (key/value hash slice). The problem was in the 1st sigil `@`. in that form it returns really a values. :) Good to have you. ;) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sub TO_JSON { return { %{ shift() } }; }
                     | |  |
                     | |  L_ 1. pull first parameter from `@_`
                     | |        (hashref/blessed or not)
                     | |     
                     | L____ 2. dereference hash (returns key/value list)
                     |
                     L______ 3. return hashref assembled out of list
```

In your `TO_JSON()` function `{ %h }` returns a shallow hash copy, while `\%h` returns a reference to `%h` (no copying).

Comment: Thanx for your answer - I edited my question to be (i hope) more clear.

Comment: Anyway, +1 because the `shallow hash copy by returning {%hash}` is new for me, need search some doccu about it. ;)

Comment: Accepting this answer, because you helped me with the slices and "shallow copy" ;) - the Moo related questions should be asked in other questions. Thanx for your attention. :)

Answer (score 5):

Perl implemented object orientation by simply making it possible for a reference to know which package it came from (with `bless`).  Knowing that a reference came from the `Foo` package means that methods are really functions defined in that package.

Perl allows any kind of reference to get blessed; **not just hash references**.  It's very common to bless hash references; a lot of documentation shows doing exactly that; and `Moose` does it; but, it's possible to bless an array reference, or a subroutine reference, or a filehandle, or a reference to a scalar.  The syntax `%{$self}` only works on hash references (blessed or not).  It takes the hash reference, and dereferences it as a hash.  The fact that the original reference may have been blessed is lost.

> I need the TO_JSON but what will filter out:
>
> - unwanted attributes
> - and unset attributes too (e.g. for those the has_${attr} predicate returns false.

Pre-5.20, hash slices only give you the values and not the keys from the original hash.  You want both keys and values.

Assuming you have a hash, and want to filter out `undef` values and keys not on a whitelist, there are a few options.  Here's what I have, using the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module:

```
use strict; # well, I used "use v5.18", but I don't know which version of Perl you're using
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $foo = { foo => undef, bar => 'baz', quux => 5 };
my %whitelist = map { $_, 1 } qw{foo bar};

my %bar = map { $_ => $foo->{$_} }
          grep { defined $foo->{$_} && exists $whitelist{$_} }
          keys %$foo;
print to_json(\%bar) . "\n";
# well, I used say() instead of print(), but I don't know which version of Perl you're using
```

The `map`s and `grep`s aren't necessarily pretty, but it's the simplest way I could think of to filter out keys not on the whitelist and elements without an `undef` value.

You could use an array slice:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $foo = { foo => undef, bar => 'baz', quux => 5 };
my @whitelist = qw{foo bar};

my %filtered_on_keys;
@filtered_on_keys{@whitelist} = @$foo{@whitelist};

my %bar = map { $_ => $filtered_on_keys{$_} }
          grep { defined $filtered_on_keys{$_} }
          keys %filtered_on_keys;
print to_json(\%bar) . "\n";
```

Or if you like loops:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $foo = { foo => undef, bar => 'baz', quux => 5 };
my %whitelist = map { $_ => 1 } qw{foo bar};

my %bar;
while (my ($key, $value) = each %$foo) {
    if (defined $value && exists $whitelist{$key}) {
       $bar{$key} = $value;
    }
}

print to_json(\%bar) . "\n";
```

It seems like a good time to bring up Larry wall's quote, "Perl is designed to give you several ways to do anything, so consider picking the most readable one."

However, I made a big point that not all objects are hashes.  The appropriate way to get data from an object is through its getter functions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $foo = Foo->new({ foo => undef, bar => 'baz', quux => 5 }); # as an example

my %filtered_on_keys;
@filtered_on_keys{qw{foo bar}} = ($foo->get_foo(), $foo->get_bar());

my %bar = map { $_ => $filtered_on_keys{$_} }
          grep { defined $filtered_on_keys{$_} }
          keys %filtered_on_keys;
print to_json(\%bar) . "\n";
```